# How does this if statement affect the time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I know that the first two loops are O(n^3), but I am not sure how the if statement affects the time complexity.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < i * i; j++) {
        if(j % i == 0) {
            for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` is not needed, you could either have `for(int j=i;j<i*i;j+=i)for(int k=1;k<j;k++)` or `for(int j=1;j<i;j++)for(int k=1;k<j*i;k++)` (`k=0` does not really affect the sum). And of course this `sum` has an analytical form too.

Comment: Whenever the condition `j%i == 0` is true, the inner loop runs. So, it affects time complexity. However, you can simply remove the loop and say `sum +=  j * (j+1)/2 ; `

Comment: This is not right. @Wander3r. It should be " sum += j; "  simply.

Comment: @ManojBanik yes.. my bad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement has a huge impact in the overall complexity of this code.

**Without if it would be O(n^5) but with if it is O(n^4)**.

Since `j` has a range from `1 to i*i` and the if will work only when `j % i = 0`.

That means for each `i, j` will work `i^2` and there are `i` cases when `j % i = 0`.

So, the overall complexity will be `O(n^4)`.

To get an idea how it goes, I just compile the code:

```
   static int count;

   static void rr(int n)
   {
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 1; j < i * i; j++)
         {
            if (j % i == 0)
            {
               for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
               {
                  count++;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      for (int n = 50; n < 110; n += 10)
      {
         count = 0;
         rr(n);
         System.out.println("For n = " + n + ", Count: " + count);
      }
   }
```

Here is the output.

**With if**

```
For n = 50, Count: 730100
For n = 60, Count: 1531345
For n = 70, Count: 2860165
For n = 80, Count: 4909060
For n = 90, Count: 7900530
For n = 100, Count: 12087075
```

**Without if**

```
For n = 50, Count: 29688120
For n = 60, Count: 74520894
For n = 70, Count: 162068718
For n = 80, Count: 317441592
For n = 90, Count: 574089516
For n = 100, Count: 975002490
```

**So, with if the complexity is O(n^4).**